# String manipulation in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, string

I have the following text, I need to extract the exception name and the continuing sentence from the file, but the file has continuous sentences without a space.

```
??????>?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????B????!48#$%&'+-/0123????5679<=@
>?CA????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
????????????????RootEntry?????????F?|?`???__nameid_version10?????????|?`???|?`??__substg10_00020102????????????__substg1
0_00030102????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????!????#$???????
?????????????????+????/????12????456789<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP????RS????UV????????????Z[????????^_????????bc????????fghijk
lmnopqrstuv????????yz?????????????????????????F?F??????????IPMNoteaws-stg-c5-feeds9aws[mazarvoiceSMTPAppender]Applicatio
nmes__substg10_00040102????????????????__substg10_10060102????__substg10_10140102????????__substg10_10150102????????????
__substg10_001A001F????__substg10_0037001F?????????????__substg10_003B0102????$__substg10_003D001F????????????????sageSM
TPBVAPPLICATION@mazarVOICECOM??@??B??+/??/O=ad/OU=ad/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=_OPERATIONSSUPPORT_OperationsSupport?+????n?T?bvap
plication@mazarvoicecomSMTPbvapplication@mazarvoicecom__substg10_003F0102????P__substg10_0040001F????????????$__substg10
_00410102?????__substg10_0042001F????????????<bvapplication@mazarvoicecom??@??B??+/??/O=ad/OU=ad/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=_OPERA
TIONSSUPPORT_OperationsSupportEX/O=ad/OU=ad/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=_OPERATIONSSUPPORTEX/O=ad/OU=ad/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=_OPERATION
SSUPPORTSMTPbvapplication@mazarvoicecom__substg10_00430102????P__substg10_0044001F????????????$__substg10_00510102????7_
_substg10_00520102????????????7__substg10_0064001F????__substg10_0065001F????????????<__substg10_0070001F?????__substg10
_00710102????????????aws-stg-c5-feeds9aws[mazarvoiceSMTPAppender]Applicationmessage??E????????A??H???EX/O=ad/OU=ad/CN=RE
CIPIENTS/CN=_OPERATIONSSUPPORTEX__substg10_0075001F????__substg10_0076001F????????????f__substg10_0077001F????__substg10
_0078001F????????????f/O=ad/OU=ad/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=_OPERATIONSSUPPORT?+????n?T?bvapplication@mazarvoicecomSMTPbvapplicat
ion@mazarvoicecombvapplication@mazarvoicecomSMTPBVAPPLICATION@mazarVOICECOMSMTP__substg10_007D001F?????__substg10_0C1901
02????????????"?__substg10_0C1A001F&????%<__substg10_0C1D0102????????????&$MicrosoftMailInternetHeadersVersion20Received
fromdalmailadsolutionscom[17216977]byblrexchadsolutionscomwithMicrosoftSMTPSVC6037903959Sat20Feb2010213019+0530Receivedf
rombarracudaadcom[1721682]bydalmailadsolutionscomwithMicrosoftSMTPSVC6037903959Sat20Feb2010100012-0600X-ASG-Debug-ID1266
681611-1c039f4d0001-azmk4tReceivedfromna3sys009aog114obsmtpcomna3sys009aog114obsmtpcom[74125149211]bybarracudaadcomwithS
MTPidoe0BsQlWiwvBTxEofor<_OperationsSupport@adcom>Sat20Feb2010100011-0600CSTX-Barracuda-Envelope-Frombvapplication@mazar
voicecomReceivedfromsource[241551448]byna3sys009aob114postinicom[7412514812]withSMTPIDDSNKS4AHC703Mnh+uM8i9u1uucP76tMiGb
r6@postinicomSat20Feb2010080012PSTReceivedfrompsmtpcom74125149120byAUSBDCaustinmazarvoicecom100023withMicrosoftSMTPServe
rid821760Sat20Feb2010095958-0600Receivedfromsource[723214889]usingTLSv1byna3sys009amx236postinicom[7412514810]withSMTPSa
t20Feb2010080009PSTReceivedfromaws-build-systemawsaws-build-system[172200110]byc0mailmazarvoicecom8138/8138withESMTPido1
KG08md020220for<dev-log4j@mazarvoicecom>Sat20Feb2010100008-0600Receivedfromaws-stg-c5-feeds9awsaws-stg-c5-feeds9aws[1020
969139]byaws-build-systemawsPostfixwithESMTPid6D6A864294for<dev-log4j@mazarvoicecom>Sat20Feb2010100008-0600CSTReceivedfr
omaws-stg-c5-feeds9awslocalhost[127001]byaws-stg-c5-feeds9awsPostfixwithESMTPid548C1801ABfor<dev-log4j@mazarvoicecom>Sat
20Feb2010100008-0600CSTDateSat20Feb2010100008-0600From<bvapplication@mazarvoicecom>To<dev-log4j@mazarvoicecom>Message-ID
<644663928511266681608162JavaMailtomcat@aws-stg-c5-feeds9aws>X-ASG-Orig-Subjaws-stg-c5-feeds9aws[mazarvoiceSMTPAppender]
ApplicationmessageSubjectaws-stg-c5-feeds9aws[mazarvoiceSMTPAppender]ApplicationmessageMIME-Version10Content-Typemultipa
rt/mixedboundary="----=_Part_51_8002724931266681608155"X-pstn-neptune0/0/000/0X-pstn-levelsS4081870/9990000CV999000FC955
390LC955390R959108P959108M970282C986951X-Auto-Response-SuppressDROOFAutoReplyX-Barracuda-Connectna3sys009aog114obsmtpcom
[74125149211]X-Barracuda-Start-Time1266681611X-Barracuda-URLhttp//17216828000/cgi-mod/markcgiX-Virus-Scannedbybsmtpdatad
comX-Barracuda-Spam-Score001X-Barracuda-Spam-StatusNoSCORE=001usingglobalscoresofTAG_LEVEL=35QUARANTINE_LEVEL=10000KILL_
LEVEL=90tests=BSF_SC0_SA_TO_FROM_DOMAIN_MATCHNO_REAL_NAMEX-Barracuda-Spam-ReportCodeversion32rulesversion32223024Rulebre
akdownbelowptsrulenamedescription----------------------------------------------------------------------------000NO_REAL_
NAMEFromdoesnotincludearealname001BSF_SC0_SA_TO_FROM_DOMAIN_MATCHSenderDomainMatchesRecipientDomainReturn-Pathbvapplicat
ion@mazarvoicecomX-OriginalArrivalTime20Feb20101600120277UTCFILETIME=[C8AD525001CAB245]------=_Part_51_80027249312666816
08155Content-Typetext/plaincharset="us-ascii"Content-Transfer-Encoding7bit------=_Part_51_8002724931266681608155--__subs
tg10_0C1E001F!????'__substg10_0C1F001F????????????<__substg10_0E02001F$????????__substg10_0E03001F????????????????bvappl
ication@mazarvoicecomdev-log4j@mazarvoicecomaws-stg-c5-feeds9aws[mazarvoiceSMTPAppender]Applicationmessage00000002BLREXC
H/O=ad/OU=ad/cn=Recipients/cn=_OperationsSupportMicrosoftExchangeServer__substg10_0E04001F#%????4__substg10_0E1D001F????
?????????__substg10_0E28001F"????-?__substg10_0E29001F????????????0?00000002BLREXCH/O=ad/OU=ad/cn=Recipients/cn=_Operati
onsSupportMicrosoftExchangeServerZxLZFu#O?rcpg125?2CtexA???????PV?U?%Qch??set2?%?3F?03???05"`cP3d36P?0?2-?100a8WARNA?ghi
b?a?utJD@BCExce0iR???SQLHEr`r???S??!a8?????ERROR??OZ?%?rpd?%?URL="jdbcmysql//?stg-c5-m?13306@/bv2?a%0o@?nn?t=t?r__substg
10_1000001F'????"?#__substg10_10090102????????????3^__substg10_1035001F????Q?__substg10_10F3001F????????????T?02-2010000
8WARNorghibernateutilJDBCExceptionReporterSQLError0SQLState0800102-20100008ERRORorghibernateutilJDBCExceptionReporterSQL
exceptionraisedforJDBCURL="jdbcmysql//stg-c5-dbmst13306/bv2?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8"!
MESSAGEServerconnectionfailureduringtransactionDuetounderlyingexception'javanetSocketExceptionjavanetConnectExceptionCon
nectiontimedout'BEGINNESTEDEXCEPTIONjavanetSocketExceptionMESSAGEjavanetConnectExceptionConnectiontimedoutSTACKTRACEjava
netSocketExceptionjavanetConnectExceptionConnectiontimedoutatcommysqljdbcStandardSocketFactoryconnectStandardSocketFacto
ryjava156atcommysqljdbcMysqlIO<init>MysqlIOjava284atcommysqljdbcConnectioncreateNewIOConnectionjava2672atcommysqljdbcCon
nection<init>Connectionjava1474atcommysqljdbcNonRegisteringDriverconnectNonRegisteringDriverjava266atorgapachecommonsdbc
pDriverConnectionFactorycreateConnectionDriverConnectionFactoryjava37atorgapachecommonsdbcpPoolableConnectionFactorymake
ObjectPoolableConnectionFactoryjava291atorgapachecommonspoolimplGenericObjectPoolborrowObjectGenericObjectPooljava771ato
rgapachecommonsdbcpPoolingDataSourcegetConnectionPoolingDataSourcejava95atorgapachecommonsdbcpBasicDataSourcegetConnecti
onBasicDataSourcejava548atsunreflectGeneratedMethodAccessor530invokeUnknownSourceatsunreflectDelegatingMethodAccessorImp
linvokeDelegatingMethodAccessorImpljava25atjavalangreflectMethodinvokeMethodjava597atorgspringframeworkaopsupportAopUtil
sinvokeJoinpointUsingReflectionAopUtilsjava310atorgspringframeworkaopframeworkReflectiveMethodInvocationinvokeJoinpointR
eflectiveMethodInvocationjava182atorgspringframeworkaopframeworkReflectiveMethodInvocationproceedReflectiveMethodInvocat
ionjava149atorgspringframeworkaopframeworkadapterThrowsAdviceInterceptorinvokeThrowsAdviceInterceptorjava126atorgspringf
rameworkaopframeworkReflectiveMethodInvocationproceedReflectiveMethodInvocationjava171atorgspringframeworkaopframeworkJd
kDynamicAopProxyinvokeJdkDynamicAopProxyjava204at$Proxy20getConnectionUnknownSourceatorgspringframeworkormhibernate3Loca
lDataSourceConnectionProvidergetConnectionLocalDataSourceConnectionProviderjava82atorghibernatejdbcConnectionManageropen
ConnectionConnectionManagerjava417atorghibernatejdbcConnectionManagergetConnectionConnectionManagerjava144atorghibernate
jdbcAbstractBatcherprepareQueryStatementAbstractBatcherjava105atorghibernateloaderLoaderprepareQueryStatementLoaderjava1
561atorghibernateloaderLoaderdoQueryLoaderjava661atorghibernateloaderLoaderdoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollectionsLoaderj
ava224atorghibernateloaderLoaderdoListLoaderjava2145atorghibernateloaderLoaderlistIgnoreQueryCacheLoaderjava2029atorghib
ernateloaderLoaderlistLoaderjava2024atorghibernateloadercriteriaCriteriaLoaderlistCriteriaLoaderjava94atorghibernateimpl
SessionImpllistSessionImpljava1533atorghibernateimplCriteriaImpllistCriteriaImpljava283atorgspringframeworkormhibernate3
HibernateTemplate$36doInHibernateHibernateTemplatejava1061atorgspringframeworkormhibernate3HibernateTemplatedoExecuteHib
ernateTemplatejava419atorgspringframeworkormhibernate3HibernateTemplateexecuteWithNativeSessionHibernateTemplatejava374a
torgspringframeworkormhibernate3HibernateTemplatefindByCriteriaHibernateTemplatejava1051atorgspringframeworkormhibernate
3HibernateTemplatefindByCriteriaHibernateTemplatejava1044atcommazarvoiceccadaohibernateModelDAOHibernatefindModelDAOHibe
rnatejava189atcommazarvoiceccadaohibernateAbstractCriteriaDAOHibernatefindAbstractCriteriaDAOHibernatejava113atcommazarv
oiceccaloggingserviceimplLoggingConfigurationServiceImplupdateFiltersLoggingConfigurationServiceImpljava104atcommazarvoi
ceccaloggingserviceimplLoggingConfigurationServiceImplupdateLoggingConfigurationLoggingConfigurationServiceImpljava95atc
ommazarvoiceccaloggingserviceimplLoggingConfigurationServiceImpl$1runLoggingConfigurationServiceImpljava69ENDNESTEDEXCEP
TIONAttemptedreconnect3timesGivingupP&uU??$???En??g=%0f-8"!?ESSAGE?!`av?+?'?fp?@dqp0?q-?DP1??oun?ly1?''!`'java?+?tSock?%
?!`4wP+?5i6?'??%@?`t'"?"?BEGIEN/0TED!X?%?PTIO9?9?4%?"?/'67/89??ACKTRB?/??<?5???@?9%??$?0mcD?o?3D?F-??y+?JoKsD1?56H?I?Mr@
?<?it>P?M?284N/I?GXK?o$??@S?Qt6??Q?STP?UN14?7Q?I?N"g??aD/?K?\?]?U??N$Ra??%Iq`??!p]?GXKG?T?GXb?M37`O?a_bcPo??ld??KF?D?Obj
Li??f<291g?hO`?fpPG?qc?k?k??!!wk?p??M?77noiH]R$??aD?p%?gd?sv?M?95toubcB>a?wOd?|?M?54?8Z?s3flP?p?$?dMhp?Ac%??5?ppnvoD??kn
?r0?}d???HDelP?g$?a?|Ip????????Qtz^D`p?W?t7???%?9g/$asp?1rPa?w?k{??ob??pbA?0?U%Ab@??Jo?`??tU?p@??e???f?P?????????/??tI??
c?!2Q?}?????M?8V~?o????????D??d?/???49?o???aL?0]?Thr!sAdv??e???%?????o??uM?V@????????????]tO?O?_Jdk?Dy$?m???P`^xK?????mv
0Z?$????w??????I??$?3L??l}GX??????w?????M??O?$\S?Mpaw?]??0??d???M?4????/?Ow??Z&Z???J@A?b?-?|?t{?]???%??eQPK?!??????M?0z_
$k????]???????????M????????do?3??`??{????A3??P?1i?zT?LazyP?l??s??22???????L]??Z????????w?Ig????C{???????????????]?]"D0C?
U?J???y???$kp?`??????M????????_Qu???o?H$?T???Q?$?Q??????????%??`%?r?%0?????????o'WP??hN?!/???_y?g??o???3pdB???U??5????!?
?%??Wrb??a-?????K???bP????M???AO#?"??P?_???&/'??&6?????1~O-Q??pg\??qs`??pt???5#F1`g}???P?5???p??!0F?0?!???67?$?2?3?4?6?9
?8'???DA?oz?<??=?>?C7?$1?P?0B?C??c?M?ENDNESTEOEXCEPTUNN?M?At3???d?]?3???`b@G]?w?p?4}Tp<644663928511266681608162JavaMailt
omcat@aws-stg-c5-feeds9aws>aws-stg-c5-feeds9aws%3A[mazarvoiceSMTPAppender]ApplicationmessageEMLt<????G???k???__substg10_
300B0102+-????W__substg10_3FF8001F????????????X<__substg10_3FF901020????Y?__substg10_3FFA001F????????????\<bvapplication
@mazarvoicecom?+????n?T?bvapplication@mazarvoicecomSMTPbvapplication@mazarvoicecombvapplication@mazarvoicecom?+????n?T?b
vapplication@mazarvoicecomSMTPbvapplication@mazarvoicecom__substg10_3FFB0102/2????]?__substg10_8000001F????????????`2__s
ubstg10_8001001F14????a?__substg10_80020102????????????d2MicrosoftExchangeServer00000002BLREXCH/O=ad/OU=ad/cn=Recipients
/cn=_OperationsSupportMAPI//00000002/00000000@00?z?`??@00?z?`????J>???j4y?f??6__properties_version10035????e?__recip_ver
sion10_#00000000????????9?|?`???|?`??__substg10_0FF60102????????????w__substg10_0FFF010268????x?&67?@9??E??$??P?@&A??B>C
P?D&Q7?R7?de>p?q?uvhwxh}???>$?>@?+??E?????#^?5???????0????o??????>??????>???????@@@@v@y@?4???2?=???+????n?T?dev-log4j@ma
zarvoicecomSMTPdev-log4j@mazarvoicecomdev-log4j@mazarvoicecomSMTPdev-log4j@mazarvoicecomSMTPDEV-LOG4J@mazarVOICECOMdev-l
og4j@mazarvoicecom__substg10_3001001F????????????{2__substg10_3002001F7????|__substg10_3003001F????????????}2__substg10_
300B0102<????~__substg10_3A20001F????=????2__properties_version100??????????????????????????????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
?????????????040040?4@??0
```

I need to extract the following keywords: `ConnectException`, `javanetConnectException` and any exception as well as its exception type.

Comment: So what's the question? Are you asking for someone to write a regex for you?

Comment: Insufficient information given about the expected format. Will it always contain the STACKTRACE BEGINNESTEDEXCEPTION and MESSAGE elements as in your example?

Comment: How are you defining "next continuing sentence.."?

Comment: FYI: look at the post source markup or the revision history. The text is actually separated into distinct lines, but it's not behaving very well with MarkDown...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using a regular expression.

Comment: could you help me more on this ..how?

Comment: the original post was tagged regex!

Answer (score 1):

I see [orghibernateutilJDBCExceptionReporter](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/hibernate/util/JDBCExceptionReporter.html) at the beginning of the message.

So use some org.hibernate.util class to deserialize the exception information?